# Inserting div right after wrapper div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So as the title says I'm trying to insert 'cookie' warning right after my wrapper div. I've tried using append as well but it adds the code after everything else is executed so div id wrapper  lots of code and then at the end cookiebar div

```
var cname = "consentCookie";
var cvalue = "on";
var exdays = "20";
var cookiehtml = '\
    <div id="cookiebar">\
    We use cookies to track usage and preferences. \
    <a href="#" id="enablecookies" onclick="setCookie();">I Understand.</a>\
    </div>';
    function setCookie() {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
    $('#cookiebar').hide();
}
function getCookie() {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    if(getCookie() == ''){
        $('#wrapper:first-child').after(cookiehtml);
    }
    else if(getCookie() == 'on'){
        $('#cookiebar').hide();
    }

  });
```

and HTML

```
<html>
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
                <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="assets/logo/logo.ico">

                    <link rel="stylesheet" style="text/css" href="../cookiebar/cookiebar.css">


                <link rel="stylesheet" style="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" style="text/css" href="css/fonts.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" style="text/css" href="css/navigation_bar.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lato_font.css">

                <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="../cookiebar/cookiebar.js"></script>
                <script src="js/jquery.color-RGBa-patch.js"></script>
                <script src="js/navigation_bar.js"></script>

                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <meta name="description" content="League of Legends patch notes in a minimalistic and modern way.">
                <meta name="keywords" content="league, of, league notes,legends, patch, notes, leaguenotes,Patch '.$Patch_No.' ">
                <meta name="author" content="Kacper Turon">
                <title>LeagueNotes - '.$Patch_No.'</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <div id="wrapper"></div>
```

I left just most important bits of code cuz there are loads of it

UPDATE: I've added the function that i use to create cookies and hide the bar, I've tried every suggestion so far and the cookiebar div lands next to wrapper as a sibling so

```
<div id="wrapper">
</div>
<div id="cookiebar">
</div>
```

And i want it to be as the first child in wrapper

Comment: Did you try `$('#wrapper').after(cookiehtml);` ??

Comment: If you want your cookie code to be inserted right after `#wrapper`, this should work: `$('#wrapper').after(cookiehtml);` Why use `:first-child` ?

Comment: I should have mentioned that cookiehtml is supposed to be the first child of wrapper and now using just  $('#wrapper').after(cookiehtml);  it is on a sibling level

Comment: where is the cookie created in the first place?

Comment: ive added that bit of code check the update

Comment: Less is more.  Paste the code in html (initially hidden), then display the element via CSS class 'visible' or not 'hidden' depending on if a cookie is present.

Comment: What is purpose of `while` loop within `getCookie()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'm not sure you're using `:first-child` as intended. You should probably be using simply `:first` or `:eq(0)`.

But even still, you probably want to use `insertAfter()` rather than `after()`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(getCookie() == ''){
        $('#wrapper:first-child').after(cookiehtml);
    }
    ...
```

should thus be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(getCookie() == ''){
        $(cookiehtml).insertAfter( '#wrapper');
    }
...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/grh1w80q/1/

Or if you prefer cookiehtml to be first node of parent #wrapper, use `prependTo()`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(getCookie() == ''){
        $(cookiehtml).prependTo( '#wrapper');
    }
...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/grh1w80q/2/

Comment: The last bit is what i wanted prepend thank you ill check this as the answer in 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

If you want `cookiehtml` to be the first element **inside** the `wrapper` div, in jQuery you can use `prepend`:

```
if(getCookie() == ''){
    $('#wrapper').prepend(cookiehtml);
}
```

this would make the HTML DOM look something like:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="cookiebar">
        ...
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: that is the correct answe thanks but the guy above was faster :P